# Chart refreshing twice

Tags: reactjs, charts

Chart created using react-chartjs-2 and chartjs is refreshing 2 times on changing values. For the first time, only the shape of the graph is changing and for the second time, the values on the y-axis and x-axis are changing.

```
const Chart = ({country}) => {
    const [dailyData,setDailyData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchAPI = async () => {
            setDailyData(await fetchDailyData(country))
        }
        fetchAPI();
    },[country]);
   const {day,infected,recoveries,deaths} = dailyData;
    const lineChart = (
        infected? (<Line
        data={{
            labels: day.map((data ) => (data)),
            datasets:[
                {
                    data:  infected.map((data) => (data)),
                    label: 'Infected',
                    borderColor: '#3333ff',
                    fill: true,
                }],
        }}
        /> ) : null

      
    )
```

Comment: why you put fetchAPI definition inside useEffect?

Comment: You might want to try changing useEffect for useLayoutEffect to prevent React from painting async.

Comment: @AnoopJoshi putting fetchAPI inside useEffect is a way of preventing react of yelling at you for not putting 'fetchAPI' in useEffect dependenciies. Which, if you actually take fetchAPI outside and add it as a useEffect dependency then you will get an infinite loop. Which you will have to fix wrapping fetchAPI with useCallback hook  etc, anyway, its not too bad of a practice.

Comment: @BaltasarSolanilla I tried using useLayoutEffect, but still facing same issue.

Comment: Sorry, not much I can do about it. I'd recommend you to create a sandbox with a minimal reproducible example, it's not too much code, should be easy. Maybe someone else can spot the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your `dailyData` state.
You set the default value as an empty array but then later you try to destructure it as an object.

```js
const asd=[1,2,4,5];

const {a,b,c}=asd;

console.log (a,b,c); // undefined, undefined, undefined

const [e,f,g]=asd; 

console.log (e,f,g); // 1,2,4
```

However, you said your chart does work after the second flash. Meaning your original empty array is not the right default value for the `useState` hook. Should use `null` and check this before you destructure it.

**UPDATE**:
The chart could flash twice if the data is loaded twice too. `useEffect` should have an if statement checking if the data was loaded already and load only if it was not. Possibly you could add another state for loading. so you would not have two concurrent API calls.

Your code would look like this:

```
const Chart = ({country}) => {
    const [dailyData,setDailyData] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        if(country && !dailyData){
          const fetchAPI = async () => {
            
            setDailyData(await fetchDailyData(country))
          }
          fetchAPI();
        }
    },[country]);
    let lineChart=null
    if (dailyData){
        const {day,infected,recoveries,deaths} = dailyData;
        lineChart = (<Line
            data={{
                labels: day.map((data ) => (data)),
                datasets:[
                    {
                        data:  infected.map((data) => (data)),
                        label: 'Infected',
                        borderColor: '#3333ff',
                        fill: true,
                    }],
            }}
        /> )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, but it is still refreshing twice.

Comment: But now it is showing the data of the first selected country.May it is not fetching for other due to !dailyData condition.

Comment: You could check if the current loaded data is for the current country. If it is not then load it for the current country. This should be in the same condition where !dailyData is.